# How can I write to an existing csv file from a dictionary to a specific column?

Tags: python, excel, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary I created from a csv file and would like to use this dict to update  the values in a specific column of a different csv file called sheet2.csv.

Sheet2.csv has many columns with different headers and I need to only update the column PartNumber based on my key value pairs in my dict.

My question is how would I use the keys in dict to search through sheet2.csv and update/write to only the column PartNumber with the appropriate value?

I am new to python so I hope this is not too confusing and any help is appreciated!

This is the code I used to create the dict:

```
import csv 
a = open('sheet1.csv', 'rU')
csvReader = csv.DictReader(a)
dict = {}

for line in csvReader:
    dict[line["ReferenceID"]] = line["PartNumber"]
print(dict)    

dict = {'R150': 'PN000123', 'R331': 'PN000873', 'C774': 'PN000064', 'L7896': 'PN000447', 'R0640': 'PN000878', 'R454': 'PN000333'}
```

To make things even more confusing, I also need to make sure that already existing rows in sheet2 remain unchanged.  For example, if there is a row with ReferenceID as R1234 and PartNumber as PN000000, it should stay untouched.  So I would need to skip rows which are not in my dict.

Link to sample CSVs:

- http://dropbox.com/s/zkagunnm0xgroy5/Sheet1.csv
- http://dropbox.com/s/amb7vr48mdc94v6/Sheet2.csv

EDIT: Let me rephrase my question and provide a better example csvfile.

Let's say I have a Dict = {'R150': 'PN000123', 'R331': 'PN000873', 'C774': 'PN000064', 'L7896': 'PN000447', 'R0640': 'PN000878', 'R454': 'PN000333'}.

I need to fill in this csv file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c95mlitjrvyppef/sheet.csv

Specifically, I need to fill in the PartNumber column using the keys of the dict I created.  So I need to iterate through column ReferenceID and compare that value to my keys in dict.  If there is a match I need to fill in the corresponding PartNumber cell with that value.... I'm sorry if this is all confusing!

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample sheet1.csv sheet2.csv

Comment: Sure,  https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4sf2wc8reqwz0e/Sheet1.xlsx and https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hdd4ovnywzi3u3/Sheet2.xlsx.

Comment: Better,  https://www.dropbox.com/s/zkagunnm0xgroy5/Sheet1.csv and https://www.dropbox.com/s/amb7vr48mdc94v6/Sheet2.csv

Comment: Great that helps. Using the data you have in dict can you tell me one example of a cell in sheet2.csv that should be updated to a specific value. The first ReferenceID value in sheet2.csv is C1619, which doesn't exist in sheet1.csv.

Comment: @MarwanAlsabbagh I edited my question for clarity..if possible.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to utilize dictWriter for this I just don't quite understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should do the trick. It first builds a dictionary just like your code and then moves on to read `Sheet2.csv` row by row, possibly updating the part number. The output goes to `temp.csv` which you can compare with the inital `Sheet2.csv`. In case you want to overwrite `Sheet2.csv` with the contents of `temp.csv`, simply uncomment the line with `shutil.move`.

Note that the sample files you provided do not contain any updateable data, so `Sheet2.csv` and `temp.csv` will be identical. I tested this with a slightly modified `Sheet1.csv` where I made sure that it actually contains a reference ID used by `Sheet2.csv`.

```
import csv
import shutil


def createReferenceIdToPartNumberMap(csvToReadPath):
    result = {}
    print 'read part numbers to update from', csvToReadPath
    with open(csvToReadPath, 'rb') as csvInFile:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvInFile)
        for row in csvReader:
            result[row['ReferenceID']] = row['PartNumber']
    return result


def updatePartNumbers(csvToUpdatePath, referenceIdToPartNumberMap):
    tempCsvPath = 'temp.csv'
    print 'update part numbers in', csvToUpdatePath
    with open(csvToUpdatePath, 'rb') as csvInFile:
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvInFile)

        # Figure out which columns contain the reference ID and part number.
        titleRow = csvReader.next()
        referenceIdColumn = titleRow.index('ReferenceID')
        partNumberColumn = titleRow.index('PartNumber')

        # Write tempoary CSV file with updated part numbers.
        with open(tempCsvPath, 'wb') as tempCsvFile:
            csvWriter = csv.writer(tempCsvFile)
            csvWriter.writerow(titleRow)
            for row in csvReader:
                # Check if there is an updated part number.
                referenceId = row[referenceIdColumn]
                newPartNumber = referenceIdToPartNumberMap.get(referenceId)
                # If so, update the row just read accordingly.
                if newPartNumber is not None:
                    row[partNumberColumn] = newPartNumber
                    print '  update part number for %s to %s' % (referenceId, newPartNumber)
                csvWriter.writerow(row)

        # TODO: Move the temporary CSV file over the initial CSV file.
        # shutil.move(tempCsvPath, csvToUpdatePath)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    referenceIdToPartNumberMap = createReferenceIdToPartNumberMap('Sheet1.csv')
    updatePartNumbers('Sheet2.csv', referenceIdToPartNumberMap)
```